# Android notification with StartForeground and NotificationManager.Notify

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

I am starting a foreground service for location monitoring through the below code.

```
string content = "Tracking started. You can change the tracking settings...";
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
   .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification)
   .SetVibrate(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 })
   .SetSound(null)
   .SetChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
   .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityDefault)
   .SetAutoCancel(true)
   .SetContentTitle("Smart Office")
   .SetContentText(content)
   .SetOngoing(false);

StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ID, builder.Build(), Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypeLocation);
```

This notification does not away with swiping or clicking as it is a foreground service and  doesn't have an intent, which is how I want it to be.

Then when the user enters a region, I create a notification with SetAutoCancel(true) and SetContentIntent(pendingIntent) as below.

```
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification)
    .SetContentTitle("Smart Office")
    .SetContentText(message)
    .SetAutoCancel(true)
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .SetOngoing(false);
var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Now I want this notification to go away with swiping or with clicking on the notification. When clicked it opens the correct intent but the notification doesn't as such go away. What is the reason for this?

Note:If I show this notification before starting the foreground service (ie. before  StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ID, builder.Build(), Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypeLocation); ) then I can swipe the notification away.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cant hide or swipe out the notification which is used for foreground purpose

Comment: Yes I understand that and thats what happens with the first notification and I want it to be like that. But the second notification is not for the foreground purpose and it is done through notificationManager.Notify() and why doesn't that go away with swiping is my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the id in the Notify method. I changed

```
notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

to

```
notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ALARM_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

and it showed both the notifications.